# FileNotFoundException open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) while upload any type of file by Samsung devices

Tags: java, android, file-upload, samsung-mobile

I want to Upload file to server by selecting the file from file manager So I have opened file manager by clicking on Button using this code,

```
 button_upload_attachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] galleryPermissions = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(CIBILCaptureandUPLOAD.this, galleryPermissions)) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        } else {
                EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Access for storage",
                        101, galleryPermissions);
            }
        }
    });
```

and onActivityResult method i have done something like this to get path of the file and had make UploadToserver function for uploading

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //ImagesData = data;
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {

            Uri contentUri=data.getData();
            Log.e("bbbbbbbbbbbbbb", contentUri.toString());

            if(contentUri.toString().endsWith(".png")||contentUri.toString().endsWith("jpg") ||
                    contentUri.toString().endsWith(".pdf")){

                photoFile= new File(contentUri.getPath());

                if (photoFile.exists()) {

                    Log.e("photoFile", "File Exists");
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    new AsyncTask<String, String, File>() {
                        ProgressDialog pd;

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            pd = ProgressDialog.show(CIBILCaptureandUPLOAD.this, "", "Compressing...");
                            Log.e("PreExecute", "Compressing");
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected File doInBackground(String[] params) {
                            return photoFile;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(File result) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            if (result != null) {
                                new CIBILCaptureandUPLOAD.UploadFileToServer().execute(result);
                            }
                        }
                    }.execute("");
                }

            }else {
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = "";
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                }
                Log.e("PATH", filePath);

                photoFile = new File(filePath);

                if (photoFile.exists()) {

                    Log.e("photoFile", "File Exists");
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    new AsyncTask<String, String, File>() {
                        ProgressDialog pd;

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            pd = ProgressDialog.show(CIBILCaptureandUPLOAD.this, "", "Compressing...");
                            Log.e("PreExecute", "Compressing");
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected File doInBackground(String[] params) {
                            return photoFile;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(File result) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            if (result != null) {
                                new CIBILCaptureandUPLOAD.UploadFileToServer().execute(result);
                            }
                        }
                    }.execute("");
                }
            }
        }
```

It works well in other devices but in samsung devices i have got

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:Xender/other/When Strangers Meet_ 3 in 1 Box - John Harker.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And my upload code is

private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask {
        private static final String TAG = "UploadFileToServer";

```
    // private ProgressBar progressBar;
    // private String filePath = null;
    // private TextView txtPercentage;

    private ProgressDialog pd;
    long totalSize = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        // progressBar.setProgress(0);
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(CIBILCaptureandUPLOAD.this, "", "Loading...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // updating progress bar value
        pd.setMessage("Loading..." + progress[0]);
        // progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
        // updating percentage value
        // txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... params) {
        return uploadFile1(params[0]);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile1(File file) {
        String responseString = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(AppUtill.URL_CIBIL_imageupload);
        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });
            File sourceFile = file;// new File(filePath);
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            entity.addPart("mid", new StringBody(memberid));
            entity.addPart("did", new StringBody("0"));
            entity.addPart("fid", new StringBody(formtypeid));

            if (app_loadid == null) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("LID", MODE_PRIVATE);
                app_loadid = sharedPreferences.getString("lid", "");
                entity.addPart("lid", new StringBody(app_loadid));
            } else {
                entity.addPart("lid", new StringBody(app_loadid));
            }

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("statusCode +statusCode");
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                System.out.println("statusCode +statusCode");
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                String success = String.valueOf(responseString.contains("1"));

                if (success.matches("true")) {
                    uploadedFileCount++;
                } else {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not uploaded. Please upload again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);
        pd.dismiss();

        if (uploadedFileCount == MAX_COUNT) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(CIBILCaptureandUPLOAD.this);
            alert.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            alert.setMessage("Reach to max upload limit");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            alert.create().show();
        }
        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        showAlert(result);
        AppUtill.deleteFolderAndAllFile(CIBILCaptureandUPLOAD.this);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a if-else statement but did not tell if the problem is in the if or the else block. You should have only posted that block and not let us guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
photoFile= new File(contentUri.getPath());
```

Have a look at the value of `contentUri.getPath()` and see that it is not a valid file system path.

Instead you should open an InputStream for the obtained uri and read the file content from the stream.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri);
```

Comment: where i can do this ? and then how to use this "is" object of InputStream  later

Comment: You should use that to upload your image. But you did not post image upload code...

Comment: `entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));`. It looks as if you are out of luck. That would be the only statement that you had to change. But im afraid it does not accecpt an input stream.